# Fetched response data is not being stored in component's data property

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

please find vuejs code below. When i access the url directly on the browser, the data(JSON) are retrieved but when retrieving the data by the http request, the data are not stored in the variable. I am using Vuejs and Laravel. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code. Thank you.

```
<script>
Vue.component('account-type-list', {
  template: `<div></div>`
  data:() => {
    return {
      typesofaccount:[]
    };
  },

  created: function() {
      this.getAccountTypes();
    },

  methods: {
    getAccountTypes: function() {
      this.$http.get('/list/accounttypes').then(response => {
          this.typesofaccount = response.body
        });
    },
  }
});

Vue.component('type', {
  template: '<a class="active item"><slot></slot></a>'
});
  new Vue({
    el: '#root',
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get the response at all or your request fails? Maybe you want response.data instead?

Comment: @user3743266, I installed vuejs dev tool. The variable 'typesofaccount' is empty. But when i feed the variable with a dummy data, i get the dummy value. response.data also fails. When i copy paste the url 'http://mysite/list/accounttypes' directly on the browser i can see the data on the page body.

Comment: console.log(response.body) inside your then() and see what it prints in the console

Comment: @user3743266, It prints nothing

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the response callback is likely not your component.

Try:

```
getAccountTypes: function() {
  var component = this;
  this.$http.get('/list/accounttypes').then(response => {
      component.typesofaccount = response.body
    });
},
```

Comment: You mentioned in the above comments that it prints nothing when you log response.body, so it seems like you have a different issue than your question presents (your request is not responding correctly)

Comment: I imported `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.4"></script>` on the main layout. I had to import this on the child blade template. Now it works. Is this the right way? Do i have to import the script with every child template? Thank you.

Comment: You have to make sure the vue script is before your own script in html. Good way to do it is with [stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#stacks). Just put one in your main layout and every time you need to add something do @push

Answer (score 0):

Had to import

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.4"></script>
```

in the child blade template not in the main layout.